# Почему нет причины тревоги "Текст указан картинкой"?

Tags: предложение

Существуют вопросы, которые адекватны *(они в меру развёрнуты и человек не просто принёс учебное задание)*, но они ужасно оформлены. Это может включать в себя:

1. Проблемы с грамматикой и орфографией, которые вредят пониманию вопроса.
2. Код / вопрос в виде картинки.
3. Путанные формулировки или слишком много "воды", что также вредит пониманию вопроса.

Но, что удивительно, я не нашёл подходящего пункта тревоги ни для одной из вышеуказанных проблем. Почему нет тревоги, которая обозначала бы именно *низкое качество вопроса с точки зрения оформления*? На самом деле уже есть причина тревоги **"Непонятна суть вопроса"**, но она относится именно к содержимому, а не форме вопроса:

> В этот вопрос следует включить больше подробностей и уточнить
> проблему.

На мой взгляд необходимо тревога для вопросов, у которых проблема именно с формой, представлением, такие вопросы действительно встречаются довольно часто. Повода закрывать их нет, но фактически они бесполезны, потому что вряд ли в них что-то поймёт сторонний человек, который пришёл с поисковика. Это вопросы не для базы знаний, это одноразовые вопросы. Вот, например: [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1219726/php-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%83-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D1%83-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8), [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1219708/%D0%9E%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0-2), [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1219691/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BA-%D0%90%D0%9F%D0%98-%D0%BE%D1%82-yandex).

Вопрос по второй ссылке, например, может быть и будет решён, но не принесёт больше никому пользы. Он не будет частью базы знаний, потому что никто больше с такой же ошибкой не сможет найти его - ведь ошибка не написана текстом, а нарисована на картинке. А в первом и третьем вопросе не так легко понять, что автор имел в виду.

Я предлагаю добавить для таких вопросов новую причину тревоги **"Необходимо улучшить оформление"** для вопросов с ошибками, плохо сформулированных вопросов и вопросов, где текст указан картинкой.

**UPD:** Такая причина есть для установки тревог на ответы: **"Необходимо удалить из-за проблем с качеством"**. *Ответ имеет серьёзные проблемы с форматированием или контентом. Ответ вряд ли удастся исправить с помощью правок, поэтому его необходимо удалить.* Почему похожей причины нет для вопросов?

Answer (score 1):

Такая причина не нужна. Я закрываю такие вопросы по причине:

> Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример.

> ... **и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе**...

То есть нужен код прямо в вопросе. А не картинка с кодом прямо в вопросе ;) Этого достаточно я думаю. Некоторые люди закрывают такие вопросы по другой причине:

> Вопрос вызван проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится, или опечаткой. Хотя похожие вопросы могут быть уместны на этом сайте, решение для этого вопроса вряд ли поможет будущим посетителям. Обычно можно избежать подобных вопросов написанием и исследованием минимальной программы для воспроизведения проблемы до публикации вопроса.

Тут так сказать более глубокий смысл. Имеется ввиду то, что картинка эта больше не воспроиводиться. То есть гуглить будешь текст — и картинку эту ты не найдешь, а → и сам вопрос.

Доп. причина не нужна. Другие причины не годятся.

Comment: Согласен. К ситуации, когда код указан картинкой подходит более чем. Однако я писал ещё и о `для вопросов с ошибками, плохо сформулированных вопросов и вопросов, где текст указан картинкой.`. Какую в таком случае тревогу использовать, если автор просто неграмотный или написал бессвязную околесицу?

Comment: @Zhenyria используйте «Непонятна суть вопроса»

Comment: @Danis но это не будет правдой. Суть вопроса имеет отношение к содержимому, потому что: `В этот вопрос следует включить больше подробностей и уточнить проблему.` Автор мог и подробности все и указать и проблему уточнить, просто сделал это некрасиво. Я об этом и говорю, именно о форме.

Бывает же такое, что вопрос неплох, но сторонний человек разбираться в нём не будет, потому что, например, текст простынёй идёт.

Answer (score -6):

Потому что вопросы с кодом на картинках закрывать не надо.

А остальное перечисленное вообще надо брать и править.

Comment: Разумеется. Но не всегда понятно, что автор имел в виду, а никто кроме автора и не объяснит. И кто должен переводить код с картинки? Разве не сам автор? Такие вопросы висят и их никто не трогает - всем лень, включая автора. Так и получается, что вопрос вроде неплохой, но по факту он бесполезен из-за ужасного оформления.

Comment: @Zhenyria, я сказал "остальное", т. е. картинку перепечатывает сам автор.

Comment: Ну так в том и вопрос. Многие ли авторы перепечатывают картинки? Поставленная тревога стимулировала бы их к этому.