# Не давать публиковать вопрос с картинками без кусков кода

Tags: предложение

Уверен, что не только меня раздражают вопросы, в которых присутствует картинка или даже несколько, но при этом нет кусков кода, который в этих картинках пытаются показать. А нельзя ли настроить редактор формы вопроса так, чтобы если автор вопроса картинку добавил, но не добавил кусков кода или сниппетов html + css + js, к примеру, то попросту не позволять такой вопрос опубликовать?

Comment: на картинках не всегда код, и код не всегда нужен в вопросе.

Comment: В таком случае. предложение действительно глупое. Вопрос можно крыть.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Полезны ли вопросы-картинки и как можно улучшить ситуацию?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5298/) и [Почему нет причины тревоги "Текст указан картинкой"?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11227/176217).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, уже было кучу раз. Код в вопросе необязателен и вполне может быть, что спрашивающий не знает как сделать и просто спрашивает прикладывая макет. Или просто прикладывает какую-то схему к задаче на графы или что-то ещё.

Единственный проблемный тип скриншотов - это скриншоты кода. Да и то иногда нужны. В любом случае, их просто так автоматикой не определить, по крайней мере, пока.

Comment: Я не против скриншотов вообще. Имелись в виду вопросы, где скриншоты есть. а кусков кода нет. Но и вы, и в комменте выше уже пояснили, в чём я неправ. ))